# MySQL/SQL query for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables and I’m trying to do a query on searching student by their IDs “studentID”. When I run the query below, MySQL or SQL Server freezes(loading…). Any suggestion? Not all the tables are listed. Thanks.

**TABLES:**

***students***

```
•   studentsID  Int Pkey
•   Fname   string
•   Lname   string …    
•   studentsGender  Int Fkey
•   studentsGender  int Fkey
•   studentsRezAddressID    int Fkey
•   studentsBirthID int Fkey
•   studentsParentsID   int Fkey
```

***student_address:***

```
•   RezAddressID    Int Pkey
•   RezStreet   Varchar
•   RezCity Int Fkey
•   RezState    int Fkey
•   RezDistrict int Fkey
•   RezCountry  int Fkey
•   RezZipcode  int
```

***student_edu:***

```
•   eduID   Int Pkey
•   eduAcadYear Int Fkey
•   eduAdmitionTest Varchar
•   scholarship Varchar
•   study   Int Fkey
•   classroom   Int Fkey
•   studentStatus   Int Fkey
•   testStatus  Int Fkey
•   additionalInfo  Varcha
```

r

***Academic_years***

```
academicID  Int Pkey
academicYear    VarChar
```

***Cities***

```
cityID  Int Pkey
city    VarChar
```

***Countries***

```
countryID   Int Pkey
country VarChar
```

***Countries***

```
districtsID Int Pkey
district    VarChar
```

***ethnicities***

```
ethnicityID Int Pkey
ethnicity   VarChar
```

***grads***

```
gradID  Int Pkey
grad    VarChar

SELECT
students.studentsID,
students.studentsLname,
students.studentsMname,
students.studentsFname,
students.studentsMobile,
students.studentEmail,
students.joined_date,
genders.gender,
ethnicities.ethnicity,
races.races,
student_address.RezStreet,
student_address.RezZipcode,
grads.grad,
rooms.rooms,
studies.study,
student_edu.additionalInfo,
student_status.student_status,
academic_years.academicYear,
teststatus.testStatus,
student_edu.scholarship,
student_birth_place.birthDate,
cities.city,
states.states,
countries.country,
districts.district   
FROM
    (
        students,
        student_edu,
        student_address,
        studies,
        rooms,
        student_status,
        teststatus,
        academic_years,
        grads,
        races,
        genders,
        ethnicities,
        student_birth_place,
        districts,
        cities,
        states,
        countries
    )
WHERE students.studentsID = “00012” ;
```

I did Use JOIN Statement as well, but the issue still persisting.

> `INNER JOIN grads As studGrad ON studentsEduID = student_edu.eduID
>   INNER JOIN studies AS studyOption ON student_edu.study = studies.studiesID 
>   INNER JOIN rooms AS classRoom ON student_edu.classroom = rooms.roomsID
>   INNER JOIN student_status AS stat ON student_edu.studentStatus = student_status.student_statusID
>   INNER JOIN testStatus AS admiTest ON student_edu.testStatus = testStatus.testStatusID
>   INNER JOIN student_address AS studAddre ON students.studentsRezAddressID = student_address.RezAddressID
>   INNER JOIN student_birth_place AS stubBirth ON students.studentsBirthID = student_birth_place.birthID 
>   INNER JOIN cities AS ville ON student_address.RezCity = cities.cityID
>   INNER JOIN states AS province ON student_address.RezState = states.statesID 
>   INNER JOIN districts AS commune ON student_address.RezDistrict = districts.districtsID
>   INNER JOIN countries AS pays ON student_address.RezCountry = countries.countryID`

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Seems you have no studentID  in related  tables (student_addres, student_edu) so  how you join the infor related  to a student ?

Comment: Oh my... you build a Cartesian product of 17 tables... I don't know the cardinalities of the tables but it is likely you build a huuuge result there. The DBMS doesn't freeze, it is just busy dealing with that tons and tons of data... Try to use joins with join conditions.

Comment: that would make a production server go down lol

Comment: The students table has student_address FKey, because the same address can be used by multiple students. That is why student_address  doesn't have studentID

Comment: I used Join as well but the result still the same

Comment: LOL.... I'm not a DB developer or Admin. that's why I posted for your expertise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a base query, like next one, and on each step add information from another table using a JOIN clause, for example:

```
SELECT
    students.*,
    student_address.*
FROM
    students
LEFT JOIN
    student_address ON student_address.RezAddressID = students.studentsRezAddressID
WHERE
    students.studentsID = 12;
```

Go this way until you get an error or the query hangs. Also, why you compare the studentsID column with a string on the WHERE clause, since studentsID is an integer column?

If this base query works, then i will help you progressively include more information, just tellme...

Comment: Thank you @D.Smania, I followed what suggested and I successfully run the query without error. But I didn't quite understand what you meant about "why you compare the studentsID column with a string on the WHERE clause, since studentsID is an integer column?"

Comment: That was related with this part of your original code: `WHERE students.studentsID = “00012” ;`. The column studentsID of your table students have **INTEGER** type, but you are comparing it with the string **"00012"**. Some engines use automatic cast of types for sanity, but it will be better if you compare it with the integer number 12 instead, like this: `WHERE students.studentsID = 12;`

Comment: The **"00012"**  is not a string, it is an Integer but it has attribute UNSIGNED ZEROFILL, that why is has the zero at the begging . I could use **12**  as well and works fine. Thank you again. .

Comment: Ok, sure it is not a string when you use double quotes around it, i have no experience with the zerofill attribute, but the quotes giveme the idea of a string value, i will expect this sintax in your case: `WHERE students.studentsID = 00012`

Comment: You are completely  right, @D.Smania. It was my mistake, after a long time of struggling.

Comment: You are welcome! Anyway, most engines use "auto-cast" of types on these cases, so the queries works normally. On other plane, could you mark my answer as useful, or if you already chose it like the best answer, you can't do it? Sorry for this, but i'm new to the platform and i'm curious about this.

Comment: Yea, but it have 0 votes. I just want to know if you have permissions for vote up the answer too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. But when I will have the permission, I will vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid such big result set. There are several option to do that.

Option 1 : Select minimum number of columns you need.

Option 2 : Use paging to get limited number of rows in result set

Answer (score 0):

Go with the LEFT JOIN and follow the TOP DOWN APPROACH such as.

Students Table

```
  •   studentsID  Int Pkey
  •   Fname   string
  •   Lname   string …    
  •   studentsGender  Int Fkey
  •   studentsGender  int Fkey
  •   studentsRezAddressID    int Fkey
  •   studentsBirthID int Fkey
  •   studentsParentsID   int Fkey
```

In the above table, First of all, Select all Fkey and check data is require or not if require then join otherwise leave it, if you follow this strategy then maybe you will get the results.